# MSBuild deploy only - no build

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, msbuild-15

Is there anyway to do the publish/deploy part of a `/p:DeployOnBuild=true` call to MSBuild? For instance, doing the build in one call, then the publish (file copy) in another call.

There is an [issue with MSBuild 15 and publish profiles](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901) when called from command line.

Comment: Issue fixed by Microsoft.

Comment: Any news would be cool.

Comment: @AlecvonBarnekow: fixed in May 2017 (see previous comment)

Comment: I think they are adding this option into MSBuild. See discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5331).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A post on Github addressing the same concern raised by you has provided a solution.

> You can find documentation on how to use PublishProfiles from
>   commandline here - https://github.com/aspnet/websdk#folder-publish
>
> Here is a sample project with a PublishProfile:
>   https://github.com/vijayrkn/dotnetpublishprofilesample/blob/7dac43543173b4ce908921106cc84d810c6dc623/WebPublishCommandlineSample/Properties/PublishProfiles/SampleFolderProfile.pubxml
>
> MSBuild command to publish to a folder using the above publish
>   profile:
>   https://github.com/vijayrkn/dotnetpublishprofilesample/blob/7dac43543173b4ce908921106cc84d810c6dc623/PublishCommandline.txt
>
> I would be happy to take a look at the issue if some one can provide
>   me a sample project & msbuild command that is not working.

Source: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901#issuecomment-377140715

Hope it provides the needed information

Note: issue was fixed by Microsoft - https://github.com/dotnet/cli/pull/8996 as part of [2.1.3xx milestone](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/milestone/17?closed=1)

Comment: Thanks but issue has already been fixed (May 2017) as said in comments, and original link is already to this issue (#1901) :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. rather close your question or if prefer accept my answer so in the future whoever look for similar issue will have his answer noted. If that fine with you.

Oho and, I don't do it for getting up-votes, just for the sake of Q&A